# "Many Japaneses" or "Many Japanese people"? Which one is more common?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Ok, in [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/japanese?q=Japanese)

**Japanese** (n): a person from Japan. Ex: *She ​married a Japanese.*

**The Japanese** [plural] (n): the ​people of Japan. Ex: *The Japanese make ​excellent ​cars.*

**Japanese** (a): belonging to or ​relating to Japan, ​its ​people, or ​its ​language. *Ex: the Japanese ​stock ​market*

So, "**Many Japaneses**" or "**Many Japanese people**"? Which one is more common?

I feel that "**Many Japaneses**" is a bit strange

Comment: "Many Japanese" or "many Japanese people".

Comment: I hope you mean "many Japanese". There is no "many Japaneses".

Answer (score 2):

The word Japanese is used as a singular and plural noun; it's incorrect to say Japaneses as a plural noun.

You can say either many Japanese (as a plural noun) or many Japanese people (as an adjective), but I think the latter is more common.

Answer (score 1):

As a native speaker, "Many Japanese people" would be my preferred choice. Your meaning is very clearly stated in using it. I'm not sure as to why, but I find using "Japanese" as a noun to refer to the people of Japan without the definite article to be really strange to the ear.